Left-aligned and centered text on same line (not equations)
In the style which I'm sort of copying, dates are printed against the left margin and the entry's heading (which doesn't need to conform to LaTeX sectioning commands) is centered.
I have borrowed code from another answer but it didn't produce what I expected; the centered text is missing (I admit that manipulating this is a bit outside of my wheelhouse.) I don't think that the centering group or center environment are what I want (centering would be it if I didn't need the date to be to the left just inside the margin.
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{makecell}

\newlength{\LeftItem}
\newlength{\CenterItem}

\newcommand{\entry}[2]{%
  \par
  \settowidth{\LeftItem}{ #1}%
  \settowidth{\CenterItem}{\Large #2}%
  \noindent
  \makebox[0pt][l]{\ #1}\hfill
  \makebox[0pt]{%
    \ifdim\LeftItem>.5\dimexpr\linewidth-\CenterItem\relax
      \makecell[t]{\strut \\ #2}%
    \else
  \par
}%
}

\begin{document}

\entry{25.}{S. Gulielmi Abbatis.}


\end{document}




as long as your centred text will never be long enough to over-print the number you can simply do
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{showframe}


\newcommand{\entry}[2]{%
  \par
  \noindent
  \makebox[0pt][l]{#1}%
  \makebox[\textwidth]{\Large #2}}

\begin{document}

\entry{25.}{S. Gulielmi Abbatis.}


\end{document}

You were losing the text, and getting a warning about \ifdim not finished as you should have something like #2\fi where you had \par

Thank you, this should work (both do, but for now I prefer this output).

Why not simply use \hfill{}?
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}


\NewDocumentCommand\entry{mm}{
#1\hfill{}#2\hfill{}}

\begin{document}
\entry{25.}{S. Gulielmi Abbatis.}
\end{document}


that does not centre #2 in the page.
